# Constructing Android Samsung (Heimdall) Firmware files

Tags: android, android-source, samsung-mobile, firmware

Most android phones use fastboot to flash system and kernel images.

Samsung Galaxy S family phones are different; there are a bunch of components that get flashed with a tool called Heimdall.

So what ARE all of these images/partitions? How do they correspond to the system image that is built in the default AOSP build?

Most importantly of all: how do I construct these from the Android source code?

- PIT
- FactoryFS
- Kernel (this one I get.)
- Param.lfs
- Primary bootloader
- Secondary bootloader
- Cache
- Database Cache
- Modem (this one I get.)

Here's a picture of the front-end, which at least shows the common partition options. There are actually many more in the command line tool -- none of which are documented. (Or, are they?)

http://alexsleat.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Screenshot-1.png

Answer (score 0):

For flashing Android Phoens/Tablets/Phablets there is a tool called [Odin](http://www.google.co.in/url?q=http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=581913&d=1304094576&sa=U&ei=gTmXUO_nOYXprQewhYCYCw&ved=0CBwQFjAB&usg=AFQjCNFxuhEbROR6kq5i4IzIl-tpOrCoBA) .Files can be flashed in two ways .
Either Option 1 (PIT)  : It is the compressed Kernel image file and factoryfs.img

or Option(2) which has follwoing section : 
PDA - It is the Android Filesystem image(The one you get after compiling the android source code in the Android Directory using make command in the out/product// folder.
PDA is generally made up of sysimage, userdata , and boot .Its a archive file for these three files.Some time you have to include/exclude the sign_image to flash on the commercialized product.

Phone - This is the modem image.

CSC - This is the image which changes from region to region (kind of locale image) which has the configuration for enabling the languages(for a particular operator in teh region)  and similiar to this other region specific settings.

You can more info on this on : [xda developer site](http://forum.xda-developers.com/)

[heimdall](http://www.glassechidna.com.au/products/heimdall/) is a tool basically for Linux/Mac (unlike Odin which runs on Windows).There are both GUI and command line utility avalaible for heimdall.Heimdall may or may not support most of the android phones and is an open source.

Rgds,
softy